# Recuperar valor de una celda

Tags: javascript, tabla-dinámica

Tengo una tabla que la relleno mediante una consulta ajax, funciona correctamente pero ahora quisiera recuperar el valor de las celdas para poder realizar la consulta de eliminación pero no sé como recuperar este valor.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  


  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append("accion", "1");   
  form_data.append("codempleado", $("#inputcodempleado").val() );     

  $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/empleados-temas.ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  form_data,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(respuestatemas){
            console.log("respuesta temas ",respuestatemas);
        
            for (let i = 0; i < respuestatemas.length; i++) {
              desctema= respuestatemas[i]["Descripcion"];
                filas = '<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+ respuestatemas[i]["Descripcion"] + '</td>'+
                        "<td align='rigth'><span id='btnEliminarEmpleadosTemas' 
                        class='btnEliminarEmpleadosTemas text-danger px-1' 
                        style='cursor:pointer;'><i class='fas fa-trash fs-5'></i></td>"+
                    '</tr>'
            $("#tbl_temas_selecionados tbody").append(filas);
        }
        
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: El script `empleados-temas.ajax.php` debe devolverte ese valor de id y así podrás usarlo en la eliminación del registro.  No parece que lo haga, y si lo hace no lo estás usando en tu salida de `filas`.  Sugiero que lo devuelva y lo pones, por ejemplo, en un atributo `data-id="aqui_va_el_id"` del mismo botón de eliminar, y cuando se pulse recuperas ese valor para pasarselo al script de eliminación que vayas a usar.

Comment: Hola,
Si que estaba pasando el codigo pero tienes razón que no lo estaba mostrando en el ejemplo. Lo he probado y me ha funcionado, mil gracias @masterguru